# Where to place clientaccesspolicy.xml in Netbeans Webservice project?

Tags: web-services, netbeans, silverlight-4.0, cross-domain

I develop a Webservice using *Netbeans 6.9* and I use an embedded glassfish server to deploy my Webservice (*http://some_domain/project_name/ws_for_sl4*). On a different server there is deployed a Silverlight 4 client, which should have accesss to the Webservice.

I know that I have to have *clientaccesspolicy.xml* (under *http://some_domain/project_name*) however I do not know how to do it. I mean, I do not know in which folder of the netbeans project I need to put  clientaccesspolicy.xml to have it automaticly deployed on an embedded glassfish server. To have my SL4 client using the webservice.

Comment: Solution: 
* put clientaccesspolity.xml and crossdomain.xml under <projet root>/Web Pages

* open Project Properties (click right mouse button on a project root), go to Run, and delete a value of "Context Path"

* now your WS will be deployed under http://some_domain and SL4 will  have no problem to access clientaccesspolity.xml and crossdomain.xml
Because SL4 is looking for these files under the domain name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: 
 - put *clientaccesspolity.xml* and *crossdomain.xml* under /Web Pages*
 - open Project Properties (click right mouse button on a project root), go to Run, and delete a value of "Context Path".

Now your WS will be deployed directly under *some_domain* as it is required by SL4 (SL4 is looking for these files under the domain name.). SL4 will have no problem to access *clientaccesspolity.xml* and *crossdomain.xml*.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone doesn't like moving their webservice to "root", and instead prefers to have it in `http://localhost:8080/aDifferentLocation/MyActualWebService`, then placing those XMLs in the project Web Pages folder doesn't cut it.

`http://localhost:8080/aDifferentLocation/clientaccesspolicy.xml`
 and
 `http://localhost:8080/aDifferentLocation/crossdomain.xml`

would not work, as they need to be in

`http://localhost:8080/clientaccesspolicy.xml`
 and
 `http://localhost:8080/crossdomain.xml`

To achieve this, you must track down the folder where your GlassFish server is installed, let's call it [GlassFishInstallPATH] and paste the XMLs into the subfolder called `docroot`:

`[GlassFishInstallPATH]/domains/domain1/docroot/` <--here go the XMLs.
[(source)](http://marxsoftware.blogspot.com/2007/11/glassfish-and-flash-crossdomainxml-file.html)

---

In case you're wondering how you would do the same thing in Eclipse, you must track down the ROOT folder in your Eclipse J2EE workspace:

`C:\Eclipse_j2ee_workspaces\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\ROOT/` <-- the XMLs go here.